# how does the $sum functions work in this mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

the following code

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: { day: { $dayOfYear: "$date"}, year: { $year: "$date" } },
           totalAmount: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

gives the following output

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : 46, "year" : 2014 }, "totalAmount" : 150, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 34, "year" : 2014 }, "totalAmount" : 45, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 1, "year" : 2014 }, "totalAmount" : 20, "count" : 1 }
```

my question is why cant we just use `totalAmount: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } ,` instead of  `totalAmount: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },` and also how does the `count: { $sum: 1 }` works, as in whats the purpose of 1 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The group operation has accumulator micro operators explained [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator)
   So as you can see $multiply is not accumulator operation , it is only serving to multiply the values per document , to sum the result for all documents accumulated in aggregate group stage you will need to use the $sum accumulator operator.
2. On your second question you need to use the acumulator $sum micro operator to receive the total sum for value 1 for all documents , so if you have 3x documents in your collection the final sum of 1+1+1 will be 3 ( which also is equivalent to the count of documents ). In case you decide to accumulate x:{ $sum:2 } per document you will have 2+2+2 = 6 (if your collection has only 3x documents )

In your query above having _id:{day:DD , year:YYYY } , you will get the totalAmout per day/year + count of documents also per day/year , if you decide to see how much it is total for the collection you may try with _id:"total"

Comment: Thanks. So if ill have to total the totalAmounts of the collection, can I only calculate from the output provided by the first aggregation function or can I include a $project in the pipeline after the group and sum the totalAmounts as `$project:{$sum:"$totalAmount"}` ?

Comment: You will need to group again since you will have multiple documents , to have both results in one query check the $facet operation